# Auto Update Using Azure Blob Storage Electron JS

Tags: javascript, azure, electron, azure-blob-storage, electron-builder

I am developing an app with electron js. I have Azure blob storage service. I have uploaded files from the dist folder to Azure blob.
But I am getting an error from auto-updater

> Package.json file

```
    {
  "name": "mico_wml",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "private": true,
  "author": {
    "name": “MyApp”,
    "email": "contact@myapp.com"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^7.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  },
  "main": "public/electron.js",
  "homepage": "./",
  "publishConfig": {
    "provider": "generic",
    "url": "https://myappsstorage.blob.core.windows.net/update”
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build": "craco build",
    "start": "electron .",
    "publish": "electron-builder --publish always"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.myapp”,
    "productName": "myapp",
    "artifactName": "${name}_${os}_${arch}-setup.${ext}",
    "publish": [
      {
        "provider": "generic",
        "url": "https://myappsstorage.blob.core.windows.net/update"
      }
    ],
    "directories": {
      "output": "dist"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis",
      "artifactName": "myapp-${version}.${ext}",
      "publish": {
        "provider": "generic",
        "url": "https://myappsstorage.blob.core.windows.net/update"
      }
    },
    "mac": {
      "category": "public.app-category.productivity",
      "artifactName": "myapp-${version}.${ext}",
      "target": "dmg",
      "publish": {
        "provider": "generic",
        "url": "https://myappsstorage.blob.core.windows.net/update"
      }
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": "deb"
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^24.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "^23.6.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

> Electron.js File

```
const {app,BrowserWindow, autoUpdater} = require("electron");

const updateUrl = 'https://myappsstorage.blob.core.windows.net/update’;
const channel = 'latest';
autoUpdater.setFeedURL({
  url: `${updateUrl}/${channel}/${process.platform}/${app.getVersion()}`,
  headers: {
    'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob'
  }
});

autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (event, releaseNotes, releaseName) => {
  console.error('Downloaded');
});

autoUpdater.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error('Error updating application:', error);
});
```

I am uploading whole files in the dist folder. Which files should I upload?
what should be the proper steps?

thanks

Comment: What’s the error you’re getting?

Comment: mac: Error updating application: [Error: Update check failed. The server sent an invalid response. Try again later.] {
  code: 5,
  domain: 'SQRLUpdaterErrorDomain'
}